# bundle exec rake db:migrate causes "can't find executable rake" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently installed Rails 3.1 and now my old Rails 3.0 app won't rake db:migrate.  This is what happens when I try to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.  I'm on Ubuntu with no RVM

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:142:in `block in cripple_rubygems': can't find executable rake (Gem::Exception)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

When I run just `rake db:migrate`, it outputs:

```
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

which rake

```
/usr/local/bin/rake
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake' , '>= 0.9.2'
```

and run  `bundle update`

---

you need to give more details in what environment you're running this:

- which OS?
- are you using RVM?
- is this a brand new RVM setup per chance?

1) Try to run this:

```
gem list | rake
```

what output do you get?

2) If you don't see `rake` in the output, then do this:

```
gem install rake
```

and then try `rake db:migrate` again

3) If you see rake, but it still doesn't work, then do this:

```
which rake
```

what output do you get?  it should look something like this:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake
```

Comment: gem list | rake outputs:
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.

Comment: well, that's easy then!  Older Rake version is not compatible with Rails 3.1.1 -- you need to increase the version number of rake in your Gemfile!  Put this in your Gemfile: `gem 'rake' , '>= 0.9.2' , and do a `bundle update`
`

Comment: add a `:require => false`, you generally don't need to require rake all the time